# Package Installation Error while creating Xamarin.Forms Shared project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I just started exploring Xamarin for my new application. I use Windows7 machine.
I followed steps mentioned in Xamarin.Forms getting started guide and created my first Xamarin.Forms project but I am getting the package installation error saying that

> Could not install package Xamarin.Forms 2.0.06482, You are trying to
>   install this package into a project that targets .NET Framework
>   Version = v4.0

I have attached screenshot of full error message.

[image: Xamarin Forms Error]

Comment: Can you describe how you are trying to install Xamarin.Forms? It looks like you are either missing a dependency, or installing Xamarin.Forms into an unsupported project.

Comment: I have downloaded VS 2015 and selected cross plotform option before installing